# How to read "and/or" aloud

Tags: pronunciation, speech

Is this read as **and or or**? Because it doesn't sound right while speaking aloud. Or is there some other way you can say it?

Comment: I read it as either "and or" or "and slash or".

Comment: Dictionaries give the pronunciation.

Comment: I always thought of the slash as representing "and/or" itself, which would give an infinite recursive sequence: "and and and and and and and and ... ... or or or or or or or or"

Comment: If you are offered cake and/or coffee, read it "and". If you are expected to provide cake and/or coffee, read it "or".

Answer (score 11):

It's normally read aloud as simply *and or*, ignoring the slash altogether.

> This and or that.

Comment: Usually with a bit of stress on the "and or" part, sort of the vocal equivalent of the `/` indicating that it's intentional.

Comment: This is general reference and should be close-voted rather than answered.

Answer (score 6):

The slash is silent, and or, not.  Depends on the speaker and their mood.  The slash is used mostly to signal that this isn't a typo.

Comment: Good observation that it's used to indicate that both words are intentional!

Answer (score 1):

And [a very brief, meaningful pause] or [another one].

Comment: I've never heard people pause between "and/or", usually they just go on as if there is no slash, like "This and or that" (like in Kevin's answer).

Comment: @justhalf: There are all kinds of people out there, including some folks who have no sense of humor and take stuff like "and/or" seriously. Those don't pause.

Comment: Hey, don't take my previous comment negatively =) I should've ended that with a question, "Is the pause common in your place?"

Comment: @justhalf: I can always use a good pause in the right place when I'm talking. Needless to say, it has to be accompanied by a gesture or a facial expression. Long story short, if you make your audience laugh just once, they're yours.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that you consider the "and/or" construct to appear only in jokes?

Comment: @justhalf: Like all nonsensical arrangements, yes.

Comment: I believe the intention of using this construct is to emphasise that the "or" is not exclusive or, but inclusive. It is used in many formal written terms, even in my native language there is such construct.

Comment: @justhalf: Hmm. So you don't think that many "formal written terms," or legal documents, or anything, are nonsensical? Or, to put it bluntly, just silly? Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

People say it like they would "and or," or "andor."  Much like we don't pronounce the hyphen in a word with a hyphen (e.g., half-day), we also don't pronounce the slash (/) in "and/or."  Instead, we simply pretend the slash isn't there and read the word as we would if there were no slash at all.

By the way, "and/or" constitutes a single word, just like "half-day" does.  You may think it's two words with a slash in between, but it's not.  You may also think it's adhoc, but it's not that either.  "And/or" is listed in the dictionary as a single word that is pronounced [and-awr] and is defined as a conjunction that means either or both of the things mentioned may be affected or involved.

Comment: '[I]n the dictionary' is nonsense. Yes, most dictionaries list "and/or" as a conjunction (Wikipedia uses the guarded term 'grammatical conjunction' and adds the open alternative), but ODO lists it under 'phrases of _and_'. Ted Tjaden at Slaw claims it is 'not a real word' and cites Fowler's recommendation to avoid its use.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth : So you're saying believe you and not the dictionary?!  That's funny. Pardon me if I don't take you up on that offer. As for OED, it actually gives "and/or" its own entry as well as listing it under the parent entry "and." Moreover "and/or" gets its own entry in Merriam-Webster, American Heritage, Dictionary.com, need I go on? Thanks for the downvote though. Seriously, I find it completely amusing people such as yourself flail about refusing to believe your wrong with such brazen obtuseness that you'll shoot yourself in the foot to make it seem like you're right. Hilarious!

Comment: I'm sceptical of *"and/or"* being a really word because it sounds silly. That's not good grounds to not believe, but until you add a source to back up your claim then I don't see why I should believe it.

Comment: and/or : http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/and-or?s=t

Comment: and/or : http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/and/or

Comment: and/or : http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/and/or

Comment: and/or: http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/and-or

Comment: and/or : https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=and%2For&submit.x=0&submit.y=0

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan : Here are the sources you asked for.  I hope they suffice.  I didn't put sources because the OP's question wasn't about if "and/or" was a word but how to pronounce it.  "And/or" being a word was a given.  I wouldn't automatically presume a need to provide a source to prove that a word an OP was asking about was actually a word, especially when it's off-topic.  Nevertheless, I'm happy to oblige.  If you have any questions about any of these dictionary entries, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman I didn't take it as a given that it was a word as opposed to a common phrase. I also didn't feel like OP assumed it was a word? It didn't seem like you did from the phrase *"By the way, "and/or" constitutes a single word"*, so if you're going to supply new information it'd best backed up. Incidentally I recommend editing one or two of those into the answer where they're most useful.

Comment: I certainly didn't think it was a single word, but you learn something new everyday I guess. The way you say it seems clear now though.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with not reading out the slash (and,or), and I do so frequently in my speeches.

However, I am not so sure when it comes to other slash uses (male/female, towns/villages, laptops/tablets, smartphones/tablets, etc.)

I think in some cases it may be useful to actually say “slash”.

Comment: Hi Slasher, this seems to be opinion rather than factual information the OP can use.

Comment: Oh right, because the others were what? Decrees from the Grand Universal Authority of Slash Use?

Comment: I mean, did you even read the other answers? “People say...”, “I’ve never heard people...”, “Depends on the speaker or their mood”: they are all subjective. Mostly because there is no written rule, so we must go by empirical experience. And I provided mine, which has some weight, given that I write speeches full of similar instances, and they are presented at a fairly high level.