# How do I read aloud a range of years with a slash?

Tags: speech, dates, slash

How do I read "During the 2002/2003 season" out loud? Should I say the word "slash" or replace it with “and” or "to"?

Comment: Are you reading it (out load presumably) to convey the information or describe exactly what is written?

Comment: To convey the information)

Comment: Related: [What's the difference in meaning between 1888/90 and 1888-90?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/592578).

Comment: Related: [How to read 'and/or' aloud](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/298208/how-to-read-and-or-aloud/536925#536925).

Answer (score 9):

Say

> During the two thousand two two thousand three season.

The purpose of the slash here is not to convey information, but simply to separate the two numbers so it doesn't look like 20022003. The season is completely identified by saying the two years it covers.

You should probably say "and" after the thousands if you are using British English. You may also pronounce the years differently. (Say them the way you normally would if you spoke them on their own.) You could say "to" (or "thru" if you are in North America) but it isn't necessary.

It would be different if you were talking about something longer than a season and which could potentially cover more than two years.

Comment: Although I seem to remember a lot of debate from the 00s about how to pronounce years like 2002. "Two thousand and two", "Two thousand two", "Twenty oh two", etc.

Comment: Yes, I haven't cast my vote because I've always heard "two thousand and two" maybe the "and" is omitted in American English and/or in fast speech

Comment: If this is American English, please tag your answer with `[tag:american-english]`. This answer is not appropriate for British English.

Comment: As a British English speaker I would now say (because I’m accustomed to saying years like 2015 and 2024 in a particular way) “Twenty-oh-2 Twenty-oh-3 season”, probably without an intervening “to”. But others may do otherwise. You’d really have to conduct a survey to find out.

Answer (score 1):

[british-english](/questions/tagged/british-english)

Replace the slash with *to,* and read *2002* and *2003* the way you normally would ("two thousand and two" or "twenty-oh-two" or whatever).

It would be understood without the *to* provided that the intonation introduced a comma and was pronounced with a **short** comma-like break, "two thousand and two, two thousand and three".

What British English doesn't do is simply run them together.

Comment: Neither does American English.